# How to get content from HTML page and print in Python?

Tags: python, html

I want to take the current 'max' forecast value on this page: http://www.bom.gov.au/nsw/forecasts/sydney.shtml?ref=hdr and print that value via Python.

How would I go about doing this? (Apologies if this is a very basic question, very new to programming!)

N.B I currently have Python 3.3.0 installed on a Mac

Comment: I'd recommend checking out some of the books and tutorials listed in the [python tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info). That way, your next questions could be more specific and more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

```
In [1]: import lxml.html as lh

In [2]: doc = lh.parse('http://www.bom.gov.au/nsw/forecasts/sydney.shtml?ref=hdr')

In [3]: doc.xpath('.//div[@class="day main"]//em[@class="max"]/text()')
Out[3]: ['21']
```

*But*, I guess what you really want to do is take a look at a [web scraping tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52wxGESwQSA).